# Computer turns off Unexpectedly because of overheating

Tags: windows-7, cpu, cooling, overheating

My System turns off unexpectedly after about 8-10 minutes of usage. When it turns off, I turn it on again and go to BIOS where I see that my CPU temperature is 91°C!

If I wait for 8-9 hours to cool down and then boot the PC again it will still shut down after 30 minutes of usage. When I do the same in Safe Mode, it does not turn off!

Okay, You might me saying that why I am not using it in safe mode instead of Posting Question here. So, The answer is that Safe mode does not support Antivirus which is essential for the protection.

I have cleaned the Fans but still, nothing works.
Any Help would be Appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Less than 10 minutes of usage before overheating is pretty quick, which makes a hardware failure likely. Check if all fans are actually *working*, especially the fan(s) on any graphics card you have installed. GPUs produce *a lot* of heat, and when the system activates the accelerated graphics in normal mode, it'll quickly overheat when cooling is not sufficient.

Generally, you have to find out which component overheats. Typical culprits are CPU and graphics card, most often caused by broken fans. Let the machine run for a few minutes, and **carefully** check by bringing your finger *near* those components which are too hot. Too hot is anything which would burn you, after 5 minutes idling. You should be able to locate the hot parts inside the computer easily.

If the CPU overheats and the fan seems to be working normally (little noise, moving freely), there's the possibility that the thermal pad/paste between CPU and fan assembly has dried out or otherwise diminished, which can be replaced for a few cents by a knowledgable person. Unfortunately you can't see this from outside, and if this happens, this *usually* wouldn't cause the machine to overheat *that* quickly, but rather after prolonged use.

**To sum this up**: Don't bother looking for a "software problem". Check which component actually overheats, then have a close look at any cooling parts of that component. Replace broken cooling assemblies or components. Done.

Comment: Interesting: why this answer was downvoted? This answer is a nice one, I would accept it if I was the OP.

Comment: Not my downvote, but I guess it is because the OP already states that the **CPU** is 91°C after the PC got rebooted and that the answer ignores that and tries to give a very general souned answer without explicitly specifying that (s)he assumes an on-die GPU.

Comment: So, when ruling out software: given the difference between safe mode and a regular boot, only the graphics card could be the culprit then?

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

1. Of your computer shuts down unexpectedly (well, not quite unexpected, but never mind that) and the CPU is that hot then your have a cooling problem. This is a **hardware problem** and you were right to clean the fans.
2. The difference between shutting down in 8-190 minutes when booting windows in normal mode vs 30-ish minutes in safe mode points to **software** influence.
   This can be as simple as safe mode running a lot less programs and stressing the CPU a lot less, or some erroneous not starting in safe mode.

To solve this start with identifying the problem:

- First boot into the BIOS. Go to the section which shows the CPU temperature. Does this rise rapidly and does the computer shut down after 8-10 minutes?
  If it does then you have one of the many BIOSes with busy waiting which stresses on core to the max. -> Conclusion. Hardware problem since the cooling show be able to live with that and more.
- Next attempt: Boot windows in non-safe mode. RUn the task manager. Is any program trying to use the CPU all the time? (E.g. do one or more core peak to 100%). If that is the case you still have a hardware problem and a software problem. The software problem is merely making the hardware problem more visible.

Lastly, look at the fans and the airflow.

- Is the access to the cooling vent blocked? (If it is move the computer).
- Are the fans oriented in the correct direction. (When cleaning them you may have reversed them. Of you have two fans and one of them is reversed you will get very poor airflow).
- And lastly the most obvious one: When you cleaned the fans, did you remove them from the CPU while cleaning them? If you did, then did you **properly** re-attach them?
  Properly means with new thermal paste and with the right amount of thermal paste. Of if the system used a thermal pad with a new thermal pad.